# How can i perform a GET request from a separate php file to a uri in my cakephp platform

Tags: web-services, cakephp, rest

I'm new with cakephp and I've just finished putting my controllers, models and views in place.I am able to get information from my database through the browser, but i want to achieve this using a seperate php file where i perform a get request. How can i perform a GET request from a separate php file to a uri in my cakephp platform?

Comment: So for example: you have http://www.yourdomain.com/controller/action/param and that outputs something from your db, and you want to include that output in a seperate php file?

And if this is what you want, are you sure you want it? :D EDIT: ohhh I guess you wanna know how to pass some params to your action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want to accomplish but,

If you want to get the output of your views from another php file (script?), you could use [`file_get_contents($url)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), where `$url` is the uri to your cakephp app.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean: Its pretty easy.. add params to the end of your uri: like this yourdomain.com/controller/action/99/foobar

This adds an id and some random param which you can use in your controller with the code below... Just add them as params.

```
function action($id,$param2){
// use params here
}
```